# C# remove duplicates from List<List<int>>

Tags: c#, list, duplicates, removeall

I'm having trouble coming up with the most efficient algorithm to remove duplicates from `List<List<int>>`, for example (I know this looks like a list of `int[]`, but just doing it that way for visual purposes:

```
my_list[0]= {1, 2, 3};
my_list[1]= {1, 2, 3};
my_list[2]= {9, 10, 11};
my_list[3]= {1, 2, 3};
```

So the output would just be

```
new_list[0]= {1, 2, 3};
new_list[1]= {9, 10, 11};
```

Let me know if you have any ideas. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Is `{1, 2, 3}` equal to `{3, 2, 1}`?

Comment: Well I know I can sort each element in that instance and those two will end up the same, so for the purposes here I'll say no.

Comment: I would look at the answers below that use Linq, as that greatly simplifies your code (vs the ones using EqualityComparers).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Build custom of `EqualityComparer<List<int>>`:

```
public class CusComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<int>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<int> x, List<int> y)
    {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<int> obj)
    {
        int hashCode = 0;

        for (var index = 0; index < obj.Count; index++)
        {
            hashCode ^= new {Index = index, Item = obj[index]}.GetHashCode();
        }

        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

Then you can get the result by using [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) with custom comparer method:

```
var result = my_list.Distinct(new CusComparer());
```

**Edit:**

Include the index into method `GetHashCode` to make sure different orders will not be equal

Comment: That hashcode will lead to a lot of collisions - e.g. `{a,a}` will collide for any `a`, `{a,b}` will collide with `{b,a}` as will any permutation... (Although it may be that you _want_ permutations to collide, in which case, nice answer!)

Comment: @Rawling: you are correct, waiting the answer form Tim's comment, I am trying to fix

Comment: Here is a hash code generator I feel is better: `return obj.Take(5).Aggregate(1, (current, item) => (current * 37) + item.GetHashCode());`  First off, I wouldn't iterate the whole sequence.  Hashes are only efficient if they are generated quickly; iterating the whole list defeats that purpose.  The first 5 or so (edit that number as needed) should be good.  If the first several are the same the lists are likely different.  Next, a good general algorithm form combining N different hashes into one is to go through each, multiply the current a prime number, and then add the next hash.

Answer (score 10):

This simple program does what you want:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<List<int>> lists = new List<List<int>>();

            lists.Add(new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 });
            lists.Add(new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 });
            lists.Add(new List<int> { 9, 10, 11 });
            lists.Add(new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 });

            var distinct = lists.Select(x => new HashSet<int>(x))
                    .Distinct(HashSet<int>.CreateSetComparer());

            foreach (var list in distinct)
            {
                foreach (var v in list)
                {
                    Console.Write(v + " ");
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really be best answer as it makes full use of Linq to simplify the problem.

Comment: Very fast solution.  This is the correct answer.  Thanks!  +1

Answer (score 10):

```
    var finalList = lists.GroupBy(x => String.Join(",", x))
                         .Select(x => x.First().ToList())
                         .ToList();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the LINQ [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) overload that takes a comparer.  The comparer should see if the lists are equal.  Note that the default equals operations of lists won't do what you're really looking for, so the comparer will need to loop through each for you.  Here's an example of such a comparer:

```
public class SequenceComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    IEqualityComparer<T> itemComparer;
    public SequenceComparer()
    {
        this.itemComparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    }

    public SequenceComparer(IEqualityComparer<T> itemComparer)
    {
        this.itemComparer = itemComparer;
    }

    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y)
    {
        if (object.Equals(x, y))
            return true;
        if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;
        return x.SequenceEqual(y, itemComparer);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return -1;
        int i = 0;
        return obj.Aggregate(0, (x, y) => x ^ new { Index = i++, ItemHash = itemComparer.GetHashCode(y) }.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

**Update:** I got the idea of using an anonymous type to make a better hash from Cuong Le's answer, and I LINQ-ified it and made it work in my class.

Comment: Note that T in List<T> has to implement IComparable. If T is a custom type, you'll have to do this yourself.

Comment: @MichaelSallmen I've shown an implementation that optionally takes an `IEqualityComparer<T>` to specify how to compare `T` object.  Good point, though. (the default equality comparer on a type without appropriate comparison interfaces defined will only check for reference equality)

Comment: @Servy yes, indeed.  It's just an example implementation, though.  Writing a good one is not trivial (e.g. see Coung Le's better implementation, that still has issues).  Perhaps multiplying each item's hash by the next larger prime number before XORing would be better?

Comment: @TimS. I would just leave a `//TODO generate hash` rather than putting what you have; at least that way readers will know they need to find a good algorithm on their own without thinking that this is fine.

Comment: @Servy I've replaced it with a good implementation.  Otherwise, I'd agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

For small sets of data, a comparer could be useful, but if you have 1000 or more List> then trying to compare them all could begin to take a long amount of time.

I suggest that you instead use your data to build a distinct tree. The building of the tree will be much faster and when you are done you can always bring your data back into your old data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to compare the performance of the answers of @Leniel Macaferi and @L.B as I wasn't sure which would be more performant, or if the difference would be significant.  It turns out that the difference is very significant:

```
Method 1: 00:00:00.0976649 @Leniel Macaferi
Method 2: 00:00:32.0961650 @L.B
```

Here is the code I used to benchmark them:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new List<List<int>> {new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3,}, new List<int> {1, 2, 31, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 6}, new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 11, 1}, new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 9}, new List<int> {1, 2, 31, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7}, new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 11}, new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3,}, new List<int> {1, 2, 31, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 6}, new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 11}};

            var sw1 = new Stopwatch();
            sw1.Start();

            for (var i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++)
            {
                var distinct = list.Select(x => new HashSet<int>(x)).Distinct(HashSet<int>.CreateSetComparer());
            }

            sw1.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Method 1: {sw1.Elapsed}");

            var sw2 = new Stopwatch();
            sw2.Start();
            for (var i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++)
            {
                var distinct = list.GroupBy(a => string.Join(",", a)).Select(a => a.First()).ToList();

            }
            sw2.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Method 2: {sw2.Elapsed}");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```